# Вызвано исключение по адресу : нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу 0xDDDDDDDD

Tags: c++, строки, классы, binary

Объявлен класс с полями и конструкторами:

```cpp
class Student
{
    string name, lastname, gender;
    int year;
    double mark;

public:
    Student();
    Student(string name_v, string lastname_v, string gender_v, int year_v, double mark_v);
    ~Student();
```

и методы - один для записи в бинарный файл, другой для чтения из бинарного файла:

```cpp
void Student::write_bin(ofstream &fout) 
{
    fout.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&*this), sizeof(Student));
}

void Student::read_bin(ifstream &fin)
{
    fin.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&*this), sizeof(Student));
}
```

В main создаются два объекта класса, один из которых инициализируется:

```cpp
Student person_1("Mark","Kurlovich", "M", 1, 9.33), person_2;
```

Затем создаются переменные `ifstream` и `ofstream`, записываем в бинарный файл, а затем считываем во вторую переменную и выводим на экран:

```cpp
person_1.write_bin(fout);
    fout.close();   
    fin.open("list.bin", ios::binary);
person_2.read_bin(fin);
    person_2.show();
    fin.close();
```

Все работает, однако на `return 0` выдает ошибку и ссылается на:

```cpp
(*_Pnext)->_Myproxy = nullptr;
```

Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x013DD252 в 8_2.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу 0xDDDDDDDD.

Comment: на какой `return 0;`?

Comment: Код бессмыслен. Такие объекты нельзя так записывать в и читать из бинарного файла.